# "Conditional" alias templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

In a type like the unspecialized template struct `pointer_traits` (i.e. `template <class Ptr> struct pointer_traits`), there exists a member alias template `rebind` that is defined to be `Ptr::rebind<U>`, if it exists, or some other type otherwise. Though I have seen a few answers on *checking* whether a certain member exists, how does one implement a "conditional" alias template like `pointer_traits::rebind`? That is, as if by the following pseudo-C++:

```
template <typename T> using type = has_type<T::U> ? int : float;
```

or

```
template <typename T> using type = if_has_type<T::U, int, float>::type;
```

I considered using something like the method depicted at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector (section "Detecting member types"), but I don't know how to implement a helper struct whose [sole] member type depends on the existence of another member type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using `std::conditional` from `<type_traits>`. It's as simple as:

```
using type = typename std::conditional<bool, int, float>::type;
```

or

```
using type = std::conditional_t<bool, int, float>;
```

where you replace `bool` with some condition, evaluable at compile-time to a boolean value. In this case the condition is the check for an existing member.

If the condition is `true` type becomes an alias to `int`, otherwise to `float`.

**FULL EXAMPLE** (Check if `difference_type` is a member type.)

```
namespace detail {

template<class Ptr>
using ptrait_diff = typename Ptr::difference_type;

template<class Ptr, bool = is_detected<ptrait_diff, Ptr>::value>
struct ptrait_diff_t { 
    using type = ptrdiff_t;
};

template<class Ptr>
struct ptrait_diff_t<Ptr, true> {
    using type = typename Ptr::difference_type;
};

} // namespace detail
```

and then:

```
template<class Ptr>
struct pointer_traits
{
    using difference_type = typename detail::ptrait_diff_t<Ptr>::type;
};
```

Implementation of `is_detected` can be found [HERE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Comment: I think op is more interested in how the condition would look rather than std::conditional

Comment: The implementation of `std::conditional` seems easy to understand, but how does `is_detected` work? Also, though I'm a fan of the new C++17 features, `pointer_traits` was implemented in C++11. Without using [experimental] C++17 features, how would one implement this?

Comment: @AliciaRose *Without using [experimental] C++17 features, how would one implement this?* Ugly and painfully. You can look up the source code for your standard library online.

Comment: "`std::is_detected` is present in C++17" Nope. "`using difference_type = conditional_t<is_detected<detail::ptrait_diff, Ptr>::value, typename Ptr::difference_type, ptrdiff_t>;`" Double nope. You can't attempt to access `typename Ptr::difference_type` until you know that it exists. And if you are trying to use the detection idiom, this is the textbook use case for `detected_or`, not `is_detected`.

Comment: @T.C. Right. Thanks for noticing. I didn't test-run any of this. For some reason I was of the belief that std::is_detected had made it into the standard. You get disappointed every day...

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem [std::conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) is designed to solve.

```
#include <type_traits>
template<bool condition> 
using type = std::conditional_t<condition, int, float>;

static_assert(std::is_same<type<true>,  int>::value,   "type<true> should be int");
static_assert(std::is_same<type<false>, float>::value, "type<false> should be float");
```